# SingleStore Execute Immediate a SP/Func inside SP from a query table

Tags: oracle, singlestore, memsql

I’m having trouble to execute immediate a SP inside a SP from a table.
because i have a lot of SP stored in a table (as a data/string).

in oracle we can use “select sp_1(:1,:2) from dual”
and running it via execute immediate. how’s singlestore do that? i get error.

please help, because we want to migrate from oracle to singlestore. i changed a lot of SP from oracle to singlestore. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use “CALL spName(args)” and have the SP include in it’s parent body (usually as the last statement) and ECHO SELECT …; statement